# Install FFMPEG on WAMP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wamp, wampserver, ffmpeg-php

I've probably spent over 12 hours trying to install FFMPEG on WAMP. I'm aware that other people have had this question answered on this site, however it does not work for my setup.

I have tried the below:

```
Download ffmpeg_new
Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file
Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)
```

My current setup is PHP 5.2.1, Apache 2.0.63. I have a Windows 7 64bit computer.

I get the following error in my PHP error log:

[22-Jun-2012 01:39:31] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.1/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Obviously I have placed the module in the ext folder.

Phpinfo.php verifies that the FFMPEG module is not being loaded. I have tried installing PHP 5.3 (with a later FFMPEG version), 5.2.6 and 5.2.9-2, but the module still fails to load. Is there anything else I should try? Does having a 64bit Windows 7 computer make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, having a 64-bit computer may make a difference. Try putting the "common" files in `C:\Windows\SysWow64` instead of `system32`.

If that doesn't work, try using [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the missing DLLs (open php_ffmpeg.dll with it)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the info. I don't suppose you have a link to an FFMPEG download that should work with my setup? I've downloaded so many different packages ...but i'm really not sure if any are designed to work with Win7 64bit. I did actually try putting some of the common files in SysWow but the FFMPEG folder i'd downloaded was labelled 'ffmpeg-php-win32-all' which suggests to me that the dlls wouldn't work on a 64bit system.

Comment: Windows emulates 32-bit DLLs if you put them in SysWow64. And no, I'm a Mac developer without any experience with WAMP (but with some Windows DLL experience)

Comment: Hi Tom, I can verify that I have just tried placing the DLLs from that pack in both the system32 and SysWow64 folder ...and it works with PHP 5.2.1. FFMPEG is now showing up in phpinfo. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install ffmpeg:

1. activate GD2 Php Extension
2. Download ffmpeg.exe  (www.ffmpeg.org)
3. Unpack the downloaded zip file. There will be three files inside: ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe, and pthreadGC2.dll
4. Download the FFMPEG windows dll files from
5. Unpack the downloaded zip file. You will need three files: php_ffmpeg.dll, avcodec.dll and avformat.dll.
6. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll in your wamp php extension folder: bin\php\php5.2.16\ext
7. Add the line "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" (without the quotes) into php.ini right on the end of the extension= section
8. Copy avcodec.dll and avformat.dll and pthreadGC2.dll to C:\windows\system32
9. Click on the WAMP icon and click restart all services. Wait for WAMP to restart.
10. Copy ffmpeg.exe to C:\wamp\bin (Note: If you have installed WAMP to a different directory, copy the file to the /bin folder in your WAMP directory).
11. The path to FFMPEG is now: C:\wamp\bin\ffmpeg.exe

    thanxxx... :)

Comment: `Mr. Manjeet Bamala` I copied your steps to install `ffmpeg` in `wamp server` but failed extension of `ffmpeg` is not installed can you help me?

Comment: The zip file from azzerti.free.fr doesn't contain pthreadGC2.dll ?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as Manjeet Barnala but copied `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`, and `ffplay.exe` into the `Windows/System32` and my application worked then.

I think it has something to do with where your application might be pointing @ the use of the `exec` command.

Running: **PHP 7.4.0**

PHP Extension `gd2` confirmed initialised via going to WAMP icon and **left**-clicking..

`WAMP > PHP > Extensions`.

..and the command I was trying to execute in PHP was:

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -ss $Second -i $Filename -frames:v 1 -f mjpeg -map 0:v:0 $Thumbnail";
$return = `$cmd`;
```

Comment: where do you get php_ffmpeg.dll?