# copy step written on stackoverflow to install FFMPEG on wamp not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm working on project for converting youtube videos into mp3 format and found this also to install `ffmpeg` on wamp server [Install FFMPEG on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154291/install-ffmpeg-on-wamp) and try other links also but `ffmpeg` extension is not installing so I also checked it at `phpinfo` to confirm its installed or not but not installed and I've `windows 7 64`, `wampserver 2.4`, `apache 2.4.4` and php version is `5.4.12` I don't know what am I missing, I spent my 6 hours to figure out but extension of `ffmpeg` is not installed yet please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Now after that I'm getting popup message twice when I start wamp server `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

> c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid
>   Win32 application.

[image]

Comment: Did you restarted wamp server?

Comment: after changes in php.ini every time I restart wamp server but not working for me.

Comment: so the first problem is ffmpeg is not installed.

Comment: "not working" is not an error... can you describe more precisely your problem please ?

Comment: actually `ffmpeg` is not installed.

Comment: How many `.dll` files I have to copy in `Windows->SysWOW64` folder?

Comment: I copied `avcodec.dll`, `avformat.dll` and `pthreadGC2.dll` in `Windows->SysWOW64`, so are these all files?

Comment: I am not sure but the link you provided php_ffmpeg.dll should be copied too

Comment: but `php_ffmpeg.dll` will be copies in `wamp->bin->php->php5.4.12->ext->php_mpeg.dll` I've done this already.

Comment: can anyone help me for this please?

Comment: Is there any one who can help me???

Comment: Do you even need a ratty, old PHP wrapper? Or can you just execute the `ffmpeg` binary from your script? See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: The extension is not installed...

Comment: You ignored my questions and you are making it difficult to attempt to help you. You already mentioned the extension is not installed. The important question, as I asked previously, is this: Do you even need this extension? Why not just execute the `ffmpeg` binary in your script? See the link I provided in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

the php_ffmpeg.dll file is corrupt or damaged and you need a new or updated one. just download and replace it. 
[azzerti.free.fr/php_ffmpeg_win32.zip](http://azzerti.free.fr/php_ffmpeg_win32.zip)